# How to set true or false if there is no record in table using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-rest

I am using Spring REST with Hibernate and i am fetching a particular record from database table passing id into my method. The method is working properly but if there is no record in table then i want false in a variable and if record exist then i want true in the variable in my json object.

Here is my Entity class **Subscribe.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="subscribe")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Subscribe implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private long id;

@Column(name="subscribed_id")
private String subID;

@Column(name="subscriber_id")
private long subrID;


public long getSubrID() {
    return subrID;
}

public void setSubrID(long subrID) {
    this.subrID = subrID;
}

public String getSubID() {
    return subID;
}

public void setSubID(String subID) {
    this.subID = subID;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

Here is my **DAO** class

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public List<Subscribe> getSubscribeById(long id) throws Exception {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Subscribe.class);
    cr.add(Restrictions.eq("subrID", id));
    List results = cr.list();


    tx = session.getTransaction();
    session.beginTransaction();
    tx.commit();
    return results;
}
```

And here is  my **Controller**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/subscribe/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<Subscribe> getSubscriber(@PathVariable("id") long id) {

    List<Subscribe> sub = null;
    try {
        sub = profileService.getSubscribeById(id);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sub;
}
```

Please suggest me how can can i do this

Comment: Please better format you code (e.g. // getter/setter in the same line with the variable). It's unclear *where* you want to set the true/false ...

Answer (score 0):

Given the way your code is structured ( where you effectively pass the database object directly to the REST client ) there is no clean way that you can do this.

I think a more RESTful approach would be to return an HTTP code that indicates that the requested record could not be found. HTTP 404 would be the appropriate code to use.

So, in pseudo-code,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/subscribe/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<Subscribe> getSubscriber(@PathVariable("id") long id) {

    List<Subscribe> sub = null;
    try {
        sub = profileService.getSubscribeById(id);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if ( sub.isEmpty() ){
        return HTTP 404  result code
    } else {
        return sub;
    }
}
```

Your client side code will need to be altered to respond to the HTTP result code rather than a boolean value, but otherwise would remain unchanged.

Comment: But i want to set a variable in json object like status:"true" / status:"false"

Comment: What JSON object? You are passing out the objects exactly as you receive them from the database. If the requested row doesn't exist in the database, you won't have an object to set "true" or "false" on. If you want to do this, you'll need to create a new object that has a boolean indicator in it, plus the list of objects retrieved from the database. To me, that seems like the wrong way to approach the problem.